# How can i prove this $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac1k\right)}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\sin \left(\frac1k\right)}}=1$?

Tags: calculus, harmonic-numbers

I have accrossed the  following sum in my textbook $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac1k\right)}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\sin \left(\frac1k\right)}}=1$ , I have tried to evaluate nominator which it gives me $H_n$ n th Harmonic number , and in the denominator i have used this approach ${\sin \left(\frac1k\right)}\sim \frac1k $ for $k \to \infty $ but i can't get $1$. Any way ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sequences 
$$
 a_n =\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\sin \frac1k}   \,, \,  b_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac1k 
$$
satisfy the conditions of the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem): $(b_n)$ is strictly increasing and divergent, and
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{b_n - b_{n-1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sin \frac1n}{\frac1n} = 1
$$
exists. The theorem then states that
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{b_n - b_{n-1}} = 1 \, .
$$

Comment: It is interesting that both versions are possible, but the one with the sine function in the denominator is a little bit more difficult because die divergence is not common knowledge like for the harmonic sum. Nice answer btw :).

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $\sin(1/k) = 1/k + O(1/k^3)$, and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k^3$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

You already reacived good and simple answer to the question. So, let us try to find the asymptotics for $$y_n=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac1k\right)}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\sin \left(\frac1k\right)}}$$

By Taylor, we have
$$\sin \left(\frac1k\right)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-1) ^m}{(2m+1)!}k^{-(2m+1)}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{6 k^3}+\frac{1}{120 k^5}-\frac{1}{5040
   k^7}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^9}\right)$$ Then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\sin \left(\frac1k\right)}=H_n-\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{6}+\frac{H_n^{(5)}}{120}-\frac{H_n^{(7)}}{5040}+\cdots$$ where appear generalized harmonic numbers. So
$$y_n=\frac{H_n}{H_n-\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{6}+\frac{H_n^{(5)}}{120}-\frac{H_n^{(7)}}{5040}+\cdots}$$ Using their expansion up to $O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$ we then have
$$y_n=\frac{\gamma +\log \left({n}\right)+\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{12
   n^2}+\frac{1}{120 n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right) } {\left(\gamma +\frac{\psi
   ^{(2)}(1)}{12}-\frac{\psi ^{(4)}(1)}{2880}+\frac{\psi
   ^{(6)}(1)}{3628800}\right)+\log(n)+\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{12 n^3}+\frac{23}{480
   n^4}+\frac{1}{240 n^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right) }$$ Computing for a few values of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 1.1734669 & 1.1883951 \\
 2 & 1.1353960 & 1.1355924 \\
 3 & 1.1123848 & 1.1123980 \\
 4 & 1.0990964 & 1.0990971 \\
 5 & 1.0903323 & 1.0903314 \\
 6 & 1.0840428 & 1.0840417 \\
 7 & 1.0792645 & 1.0792633 \\
 8 & 1.0754827 & 1.0754816 \\
 9 & 1.0723966 & 1.0723955 \\
 10 & 1.0698175 & 1.0698165
\end{array}
\right)$$